# Calculating the probability of error free products using Beyes theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

**My Problem**

> When producing a product, two errors (A and B) can occur.
> The probability that a product has error A :  `P(A) = 0.05`
> The probability that the product has error B, given that it has error A :
> `P(B|A) = 0.4`
> The probability that a product has error B, given that it does not have error A : `P(B|A*) = 0.15`
> What is the probability that a product is completely free from errors?

**Answer**:
$0.81$

**My attempt of solving it**
$P(\text{error free}) = 1-P(B|A) = 0.6$

**My Question**:
I am clearly getting the wrong answer.
I am thankful for any help and/or guidance.

Comment: Please use mathjax for typesetting mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

- What is the probability a product does *not* have error A?
- Given that it does *not* have error A, what is the probability it does *not* have error B?
- What is the probability it does *not* have error A and it does *not* have error B?

Comment: I get that P(B) = 0.1625, so P(Bᶜ) = 1-P(B) = 0.8375, I also get that P(Aᶜ) = 1-P(A) = 0.95, hence P(Aᶜ and Bᶜ) = P(Aᶜ)*P(Bᶜ) = 0.8375*0.95 = 0.795625, however, 0.79 is still the wrong answer

Comment: In answer to my three hints, you should have $P(A^c)=1-P(A)=0.95$ and $P(B^c \mid A^c)=1- P(B \mid A^c)=0.85$ and $P( A^c ,B^c)=P(B^c \mid A^c)P(A^c)=0.8075$